# transfring myob from one computer to other

Tags: myob

i have MYOB installed on one computer and that system crush due to virus, i got all myob data and program files.

problem is i don't have installer for MYOB, i lost it.

i copy all the myob folder to c:\program files\myob

and try to run myob, its giving MYOB ERROR 9004

after i search on net i found that i need to create these registry entries which i did

```
         Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

         [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MYOB Technology]

         [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MYOB Technology\AU]

         [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MYOB Technology\AU\MSC]

         [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MYOB Technology\AU\MSC\3.0]
         "JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\MYOB\\Common\\JRE"
```

now program run and after getting user name & password it give error initialization error.

does any one have idea how to run myob on system without installing it.

Thanks

Comment: which version of MYOB your using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you copying all folders, this error seems that you are missing some files/ folders.

check all the folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also copy and paste over the MYOB file in your Program files, as well as the MYOBVersion as this is where the licence is!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer will depend on which product and version you have installed and for the most accurate detail you're best reaching out to support directly.

For products like AccountRight Live you can easily re-install the software on the new computer.  You can get fresh copies of the installers from the product downloads section of your my.myob.com login.

Individual company files (.myox for AccountRight Live) can be copied to the new computer and then opened (in much the same way you would install Microsoft Word and then open a Word .docx document) noting that each file is linked to the serial number.

And lastly on a note of personal advice: run a patched anti-virus on the new machine :)